# Nomenclature alkyl halides

Tags: nomenclature

I was solving questions on the MSU website on organic nomenclature.
Out of the following questions, I got only the first and last one right.[image]
Where am I going wrong with the others?Hints would suffice.

EDIT:I got the second one correct as well.

(2)----**7,7-Dichloro-4-ethyl-3,3,8-trimethyl-4-propyldecane**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, most of the names proposed by you correspond to the preferred IUPAC names in accordance with the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*:

**(1)** 3-bromo-2,5-dimethylhexane

**(2)** 7,7-dichloro-4-ethyl-3,3,8-trimethyl-4-propyldecane (your edit is correct)

**(3)** see below

**(4)** 2-chloropent-1-en-4-yne

**(5)** 1-bromo-3-ethyl-5-methylbenzene

For compound **(3)**, you have to consider the relevant rules for the numbering of locants for substituent prefixes:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

Note that Rule (f) takes precedence over Rule (g).

In accordance with Rule (f), compound **(3)** could be named as 5-bromo-1-methylcyclohexa-1,4-diene (which was your proposal) as well as 1-bromo-5-methylcyclohexa-1,4-diene since both names correspond to the locant set ‘1,5’. However, according to Rule (g), this example is named as 1-bromo-5-methylcyclohexa-1,4-diene rather than 5-bromo-1-methylcyclohexa-1,4-diene since bromo is cited first as a prefix in the name.

[image: 1-bromo-5-methylcyclohexa-1,4-diene]